# C/C++ Multithreading: restricted shared memory acces

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, pthreads

I guess there exist approaches how to implement pthread based multithreads accessing  restricted shared ram, but could not find it.

The idea is to have several threads which should be able to share some ram with each other based on some sort of access management (like user,group,all...).

So there needs to be a layer/manager which decides if an access is granted. This surely costs perfomance. Before implementing something naive, I would have liked to see how others did this...

Alex

Edit:
background: i will end up with many tasks/processes (>1000). Due to the larger overhead of processes, I therefore was going for tasks...

Comment: Why not use multi-processes with shared memory?

Comment: Too broad, please give details about your problem. As a shot across the bow: Sure you need >1000 threads? Sounds like you might first want to rethink the design.

Comment: >1000? Yes, it's about agent based systems. Agents should be threads or processes. I could work with one process, managing the agents, then I would need to add a scheduling layer...

Comment: Hmm. One could try to use processes, suspend them and wake only some of them for a certain time. This would allow to have only a reasonable number of active processes, while being able to keep the agents states. This would be flexible with respect to the hardware, becauseon different hardware, different # of active processes could be used...

Comment: You're writing those agents, so you can trust them? Just let each agent look up in a table whether it may access something. And don't create 1000 threads. Create num_cpu threads that handle 1000/num_cpu agents each (implement your agents as tasks and add them to queues).